# Pinescript custom color for volume bar above certain value

Tags: pine-script

I want to get different colors of the volume bar when it goes above my fixed volume,
Say when volume goes above 10000, it should show a bar with dark red or dark green colour,

How can I do that?

I tried to modify with the existing volume code, but it did not work,

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Volume", shorttitle="Vol", format=format.volume, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
showMA = input(true)
barColorsOnPrevClose = input(title="Color bars based on previous close", defval=false)
palette = barColorsOnPrevClose ? close[1] > close ? color.red : color.green : open > close ? color.red : color.green ? volume > int(10000) : color.rgb(247, 10, 10) : color.rgb(16, 245, 23)
plot(volume, color = color.new(palette,65), style=plot.style_columns, title="Volume")
plot(showMA ? ta.sma(volume,20) : na, style=plot.style_area, color=color.new(color.blue,65), title="Volume MA")
```

Any help to modify bar color based on value is highly helpful.

New Code update...

```
indicator(title="Volume my", shorttitle="Volume", format=format.volume, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
showMA = input(true)
barColorsOnPrevClose = input(title="Color bars based on previous close", defval=false)
palette = barColorsOnPrevClose ? close[1] > close ? color.red : color.green : open > close ? color.red : color.green

palette := volume > int(10000) and barColorsOnPrevClose ? close[1] > close ? color.rgb(247, 10, 10) : color.rgb(16, 245, 23) : palette

plot(volume, color = color.new(palette,65), style=plot.style_columns, title="Volume")
plot(showMA ? ta.sma(volume,20) : na, style=plot.style_area, color=color.new(color.blue,65), title="Volume MA")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your normal volume colors first and then reassign the colors if your condition is met.

```
palette = barColorsOnPrevClose ? close[1] > close ? color.red : color.green : open > close ? color.green : color.red
palette := volume > int(100000) and barColorsOnPrevClose ? close[1] > close ? color.rgb(247, 10, 10) : color.rgb(16, 245, 23) : palette
```

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work, I have updated your code in my original question,

Comment: It resolved by changing default false to true, ```barColorsOnPrevClose = input(title="Color bars based on previous close", defval=true)```